# In Python, it shows: "NameError: name 'math' is not defined" and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a calculator with Tkinter and I set a variable "math" which helps the program to know which operation it needs to do (Addition, Subtraction, etc) but when I try to run it, it says "NameError: name 'math' is not defined" and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Any help would be appreciated. I'm just a beginner. Here is the code in question:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Calculator")

e = Entry(root, width=35)
e.insert(0, "")
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

def button_click(number):
    current = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END) 
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number)) 



def clear_button():
    e.delete(0, END)


def button_add():
    math = "addition"
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num 
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0,END)
    

def button_equal():
    second_number = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    if (math == "addition"):
        e.insert(0, f_num + int(second_number))
    elif (math == "subtraction"):
        e.insert(0, f_num - int(second_number))
    elif (math == "multiplication"):
        e.insert(0, f_num * int(second_number))
    elif math == "division":
        e.insert(0, f_num / int(second_number))

def button_subtraction():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num 
    math = "subtraction"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0,END)

def button_multiplication():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num 
    math = "multiplication"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0,END)

def button_division():
    first_number = e.get()
    global f_num 
    math = "division"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0,END)

# Creates the buttosn for the numbers
button_1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(1))
button_2 = Button(root, text="2", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(2))
button_3 = Button(root, text="3", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(3))
button_4 = Button(root, text="4", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(4))
button_5 = Button(root, text="5", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(5))
button_6 = Button(root, text="6", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(6))
button_7 = Button(root, text="7", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_8 = Button(root, text="8", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(8))
button_9 = Button(root, text="9", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(9))
button_0 = Button(root, text="0", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(0))

# Position for the numbers
button_1.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=1, column=2)
button_4.grid(row=2, column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=2)
button_7.grid(row=3, column=0)
button_8.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=3, column=2)
button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)

# Creates the clear button and assigns its position
button_clear = Button(root, text="Clear", padx=77, pady = 20, command=clear_button)
button_clear.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

# Creates the + button and assigns its position
button_plus= Button(root, text="+", padx=39, pady=20, command=button_add)
button_plus.grid(row=5, column=0)

# Creates the - button and assigns its position
button_plus= Button(root, text="-", padx=41, pady=20, command=button_subtraction)
button_plus.grid(row=6, column=0)

# Creates the * button and assigns its position
button_plus= Button(root, text="*", padx=39, pady=20, command=button_multiplication)
button_plus.grid(row=6, column=1)

# Creates the / button adn assigns its position
button_plus= Button(root, text="/", padx=39, pady=20, command=button_division)
button_plus.grid(row=6, column=2)


# Creates the = Button and assigns its position
button_equal = Button(root, text="=", padx=87, pady = 20, command=button_equal)
button_equal.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to learn about variable scope. A local variable in one function can't be accessed by another function. `button_equal` has no idea what `math` is because it is nowhere defined in that function.

Answer (score 1):

As @John Coleman said, math variables are not accessible for other functions.

You can add `global math` for each function except the button equal.

So, your full code will be like this;

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Calculator")

e = Entry(root, width=35)
e.insert(0, "")
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

def button_click(number):
    current = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END) 
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number)) 
    a = int(str(current) + str(number))



def clear_button():
    e.delete(0, END)


def button_add():
    global math,f_num
    math = "addition"
    first_number = e.get()
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0,END)
    

def button_equal():
    second_number = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    if (math == "addition"):
        e.insert(0, f_num + int(second_number))
    elif (math == "subtraction"):
        e.insert(0, f_num - int(second_number))
    elif (math == "multiplication"):
        e.insert(0, f_num * int(second_number))
    elif math == "division":
        e.insert(0, f_num / int(second_number))

def button_subtraction():
    global math,f_num
    first_number = e.get()
    math = "subtraction"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0,END)

def button_multiplication():
    global math,f_num
    first_number = e.get()
    math = "multiplication"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0,END)

def button_division():
    global math,f_num
    first_number = e.get()
    math = "division"
    f_num = int(first_number)
    e.delete(0,END)

# Creates the buttosn for the numbers
button_1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(1))
button_2 = Button(root, text="2", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(2))
button_3 = Button(root, text="3", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(3))
button_4 = Button(root, text="4", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(4))
button_5 = Button(root, text="5", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(5))
button_6 = Button(root, text="6", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(6))
button_7 = Button(root, text="7", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_8 = Button(root, text="8", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(8))
button_9 = Button(root, text="9", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(9))
button_0 = Button(root, text="0", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(0))

# Position for the numbers
button_1.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=1, column=2)
button_4.grid(row=2, column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=2)
button_7.grid(row=3, column=0)
button_8.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=3, column=2)
button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)

# Creates the clear button and assigns its position
button_clear = Button(root, text="Clear", padx=77, pady = 20, command=clear_button)
button_clear.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

# Creates the + button and assigns its position
button_plus= Button(root, text="+", padx=39, pady=20, command=button_add)
button_plus.grid(row=5, column=0)

# Creates the - button and assigns its position
button_plus= Button(root, text="-", padx=41, pady=20, command=button_subtraction)
button_plus.grid(row=6, column=0)

# Creates the * button and assigns its position
button_plus= Button(root, text="*", padx=39, pady=20, command=button_multiplication)
button_plus.grid(row=6, column=1)

# Creates the / button adn assigns its position
button_plus= Button(root, text="/", padx=39, pady=20, command=button_division)
button_plus.grid(row=6, column=2)


# Creates the = Button and assigns its position
button_equal = Button(root, text="=", padx=87, pady = 20, command=button_equal)
button_equal.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Good answer, though it probably couldn't hurt to add that `math` is a poor name since it is also the name for a standard module. It would be better to use something like `operation` for the name of the arithmetical operation.